# QuickBooks IDN Login

Tags: authentication, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

I get the error message

> migration to IAM required

when I try to log in at the QuickBooks IDN site. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: What url are you trying to login at? an you go to https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident here and submit a ticket to give us more information about your account?

Comment: I'm at developer.intuit.com, and click log in. Can't submit a ticket because that requires log in. admin@softgreencorp.com is the username. Tried at marketplace.intuit.com and logged in, but got blank page at next screen. Using Firefox 21.0. Trying to access setup for app - need to change prices, update version, etc.

Comment: I'll have someone contact you to get it straightened out asap. sorry about this. - jarred